# Number of hits per document in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am able to find the total number of hits, but I wan't to find out the number of hits per document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if this is what you want, but if you want the number of times a term was used in a document, see [In a Lucene / Lucene.net search, how do I count the number of hits per document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249364/in-a-lucene-lucene-net-search-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-hits-per-document)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I need the exact thing mentioned in the link u have given me.. but then I am unable to use it.. can u plz elaborate it, or give me a better solution..

Comment: it world be great if u could reply me as early as possible.. Thanks.