# Lucene. how do I count the number of hits per document?

Tags: java, lucene

At StackOverflow I found this one [In a Lucene / Lucene.net search, how do I count the number of hits per document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249364/in-a-lucene-lucene-net-search-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-hits-per-document)

But I can not define SpanQuery from code below. I'm using Lucene 4.4.0(spanquery defining is different than older versions)

```
IndexReader indexReader = // define your index reader here
SpanQuery spanQuery = // define your span query here
Spans spans = spanQuery.getSpans(indexReader);
int occurrenceCount = 0;
while (spans.next()) {
    occurrenceCount++;
}
```

Anybody can help? I would really appreciate full answer with an example

Comment: Actually, creating `SpanQuery`s hasn't changed much at all since 2.9.4.  Some new types of SpanQuery were added, but other than that.  Are you having some particular problem with it?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to define it

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to get the total number of occurances of a term in the index, as per the linked-to answer, would be:

```
Term term = new Term("myfield", "myterm");
long numOccurances = indexReader.totalTermFreq(term);
```

Comment: How can I get the number of occurances per document?

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
SpanQuery spanQuery = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("myfield", "myterm"); // define your span query here`enter code here`
```

can be used when you are interested in a single term (This example looks for the term "myterm" in the field "myfield").

Look at the other SpanQuery implementations also (SpanOrQuery, SpanNearQuery, SpanNotQuery, ...)